# What is the definitive book on developing command line apps in C for FreeBSD?

Tags: c, unix, command-line, freebsd

I'd like to do some hobby development of command line applications for UNIX in C.  To narrow that down, I'd like to focus on the BSD family, specifically FreeBSD as my development machine is a Mac OS X 10.7 Lion box.

Searches for UNIX development have returned some from Addison Wesley, but I cannot find adequate documentation for FreeBSD.  If there is a good general book on developing for either BSD or AT&T UNIX, I would be interested in that.  please note I prefer books as I learn best that way.

Thanks,

Scott

Comment: Hi amso!  It is a bit vague, but I'm looking for a good book that covers the basics...POSIX, threading, system services, sockets, etc.  It seems to me that there are single books associated with one of these topics in depth, but not a general overview. I'm looking for something like this: http://www.amazon.com/Windows-Programming-Addison-Wesley-Microsoft-Technology/dp/0321657748/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1313058063&sr=1-1

Comment: Sorry, I tried to delete the comment to add the last line and your reply just came in. Here's the comment, with the edit I meant: --> I think your question is a bit vague. It all depends on what you are trying to do. Command line applications can vary through a wide range of types, from stream processing, database applications, networked applications, etc. Can you please elaborate on what are you trying to develop or focus on?

Answer (score 3):

Stevens ["Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321525949). It covers FreeBSD but it's not FreeBSD specific. It is Unix specific, and covers all the bases you require.

Answer (score 3):

You should start with the classic: Kernighan and Pike, *The Unix Programming Environment*. The first half is a tutorial on using the command-line and composing programs; the second half walks you through the development of a simple arithmetic programming language using C and YACC. This book is the base-line that other Unix programming books will assume.

Comment: This is the very best suggestion, hands down. You cannot go wrong with K&P. Get their other stuff, too.

Comment: Indeed, you can't beat hearing the story from the horse's mouth.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could take a look at these:

[Programming with POSIX Threads](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633922)

[The sockets Networking API](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411551)

[Interprocess Communications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130810819)

[Advanced Programming in the UNIX environment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321525949)

The first three are very specific and would serve only if you need to focus on that particular subject.
The last link is a highly rated book on Amazon that you may be interested in.

All in all, if you already have a grip of threads, IPC, networking, filesystem, all you need is the internet because there is widely available documentation about the POSIX API.